# JavaScript Prototype method not found on object

Tags: javascript

From what I have read, if a property or method is not found on the object, its searched on prototype of the object. In below example, I have created an object. Then assigned prototype of that object to a object literal. I am now able to access the method of object's prototype. But not able to access same on object. Why so?

```js
var functionMaster = Object.create(null); 

//assign proto to below object literal
functionMaster.prototype = {

  printVal: function() {
    console.log('Hello test');
  },
  printNo: function(num) {
    console.log(num);
  }
}


//Works as expected
functionMaster.prototype.printVal();
//Doesnt find PrintVal() method
functionMaster.printVal();
```

Comment: you need to use constructor functions to create inheritable prototypes.

Comment: `prototype` properties are only used by `new` with constructor functions. With `Object.create()`, the argument is your chance specify a prototype (currently `null`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Then assigned prototype of that object to a object literal.

No you haven't. The `prototype` property only has a special meaning on (constructor) **function** objects:

```
function Constr() {}
Constr.prototype.foo = 42;

var instance = new Constr();
console.log(instance.foo); // 42
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(instance) === Constr.prototype); // true
```

In your case, assigning a `prototype` property to an **object**, it is just an ordinary property with no special meaning. You can verify this by running `Object.getPrototypeOf(functionMaster)`. It will return `null`.

> But not able to access same on object. Why so?

The object doesn't have a prototype at all since you explicitly set it to `null`. You either want

```
var functionMaster = Object.create({
  printVal: function() {
    console.log('Hello test');
  },
  printNo: function(num) {
    console.log(num);
  }
});
```

or

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(functionMaster, {
  printVal: function() {
    console.log('Hello test');
  },
  printNo: function(num) {
    console.log(num);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Felix. Very well explained. Also, I am not able to use functionMaster.prototype.printVal(); even when object has an prototype created by Object.setPrototypeOf because prototype property will work only with function objects (Constructors)?